# How to display directional marker like google map app does

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been searching for this but didn't get any resource, I want to display marker with direction on current location similar to Google Map app. see the attachment (blue marker with direction)

What does it called ?

[image]

Pleas help me with this, I have created a map with current location.

**Activity Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    map.clear();
    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mp.title("my position");
    mp.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
    map.addMarker(mp);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

Comment: Here's my guess how they did it. You create a custom marker that consists of a small triangle and a circle. Use this custom marker and update your current location as you walk around or drive around. Rotate the marker to match the direction you are facing. Here's [**marker documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker). I did see rotation and custom marker. Finding direction might be the trick you want to figure out.

Comment: Thanks @so_jin_ee I found the solution. If you dont provide the marker it will fallback to blue marker with direction as shown above

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `onMapReady` callback is being fired. Use the `getMapAsync` method like this, `((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this)`. This should then call the `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` method and you'll be able to see your bearing.